# Input shape of stacked RNNs

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to stack a few RNNs in series using Keras with a TensorFlow back-end. I can create a model with a single `SimpleRNN` layer, but when I try to add second `SimpleRNN` layer, I can't figure out the appropriate input size.

```
from keras import models
from keras.layers.recurrent import SimpleRNN
from keras.layers import Activation


model = models.Sequential()

hidden_units = 256
skeleton_dimensions = 3 * 16  # 3 dimensions for 16 joints
input_temporal_length = 7

in_shape = (input_temporal_length, skeleton_dimensions,)

# three hidden layers of 256 each
model.add(SimpleRNN(hidden_units, input_shape=in_shape,
                    activation='relu', use_bias=True,))
# what input shape is this supposed to have?
model.add(SimpleRNN(hidden_units, input_shape=(1, skeleton_dimensions,),
                    activation='relu', use_bias=True,))
```

What should my second `SimpleRNN` have as input shape?

The documentation of the [Recurrent Layers](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) seems to imply:

> **Output shape**
>
> - if return_sequences: 3D tensor with shape  (batch_size, timesteps,
>     units).
> - else, 2D tensor with shape (batch_size, units).

Given `return_sequences` is automatically set to `False` I tried to set the `input_shape` of the next dimension appropriately, but I get the error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rnn_agony.py", line 19, in <module>
    activation='relu', use_bias=True,))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 455, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 252, in __call__
    return super(Recurrent, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 511, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 413, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer simple_rnn_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are stacking RNNs, you need to set `return_sequences=True` and you will no longer need to set `input_shape`. This makes intuitive sense, since RNNs expect input sequences.